# VBA_Processing a value as 29160012040000TZ

Tags: vba

I created a couple of user forms which operate a data in separate report workbook. My script can successfully proceed a value in digit type.  Unfortunately the circumstances have changed and now it has to work with a Serial Numbers as: 29160012040000TZ. With that new value script after starting the Sub, open a report, but it never enter into a 'with' statement. It doesn't look for a value or doing something else. Just open a report workbook and freeze.

Below you can see the code lines where issue is present and a little description:

`Single_PHA` is a text window in User Form where user can enter a a value, proceeding value is 29160012040000TZ

```
Private Sub Wydaj_button_Click()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="N:\ENGINEERING\1. ENGINEERS\Mateusz Skorupka\PHA_Cleaning_report_path\PHA_CLEANING_REPORT.xlsm", ReadOnly:=False
    Dim REPORT As Workbook
    Set REPORT = Application.Workbooks("PHA_CLEANING_REPORT.xlsm")
    Set TABLE = REPORT.Worksheets("Main_table")
...

With TABLE.Range("A1")
        If Single_PHA = True Then
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(Single_PHA.Value, .Range("A:A"), 0)) Then
                Single_PHA_row = TABLE.Range("A:A").Find(What:=Single_PHA.Value, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
                .Offset(Single_PHA_row - 1, 4).Value = Date
                REPORT.Close SaveChanges:=True
                Single_PHA.Value = ""
                Exit Sub
             Else
                MsgBox "Numer seryjny głowicy nie istnieje w bazie"
                REPORT.Close SaveChanges:=False
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End With
```

In VBA I don't know how to open something like debugger or make the print instruction which would show me how the variables look on specific steps.

I am not sure if VBA read the value as 29160012040000TZ as string. I tried to declare at the beginning a variable as Single_PHA_STR as String and the proceed it as just text, but no wins there:

```
Dim Single_PHA_STR As String
...
With TABLE.Range("A1")
        If Single_PHA = True Then
        Single_PHA_STR = Str(Single_PHA.Value)
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(Single_PHA_STR, .Range("A:A"), 0)) Then
                Single_PHA_row = TABLE.Range("A:A").Find(What:=Single_PHA_STR, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
                .Offset(Single_PHA_row - 1, 4).Value = Date
                REPORT.Close SaveChanges:=True
                Single_PHA.Value = ""
                Exit Sub
             Else
                MsgBox "Numer seryjny głowicy nie istnieje w bazie"
                REPORT.Close SaveChanges:=False
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End With
```

I noticed that if in VBA IDE I write a bold value 29160012040000TZ, I get an error

> Expected line number or label or statement or end of statement

and the value is highlighted in red.

Could someone help me in that field and explain the nature of issues:

To reproduce a situation you can create a simply user form with one TextBox and one CommandButton. In the same worksheet as user form in a column A put a values: 29160012040000 and 29160012042027IR
Then make a sub which execute after double click on command button with code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        If Text_box1 = True Then
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(Text_box1.Value, .Range("A:A"), 0)) Then
                Text_box1_row = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(What:=Text_box1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
                .Offset(Text_box1_row - 1, 4).Value = Date
                Text_box1.Value = ""
                Exit Sub
             Else
                MsgBox "PHA SN not exist in a database"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Then try to input in a UserForm's TextBox a value = 29160012040000 and you will see that script successfully filled a forth column in row with current date. Then try to input a value 29160012042027IR and you will see that nothing happened. Script don't proceed that value at all.

So that is my issue and question indeed. How to process a value with letters at the end like: 29160012042027IR : )

I also tried to focus a script statement on one specific cell in which is a text value "29160012042027IR" that which I input into a UserForm TextBox. Looking with a debugger both of variables in if statement have the same text value, but still script miss that statement and go to else instructions : (

I mean abut: If Range("A3").Text = Text_box1.Text Then
When I change a statement for "If Range("A3").Value = Text_box1.Value Then" the same thing happen.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
        If Text_box1 = True Then
            If Range("A3").Text = Text_box1.Text Then
                Text_box1_row = Worksheets("Arkusz1").Range("A:A").Find(What:=Text_box1.Value, LookIn:=xlWhole).Row
                .Offset(Text_box1_row - 1, 4).Value = Date
                Text_box1.Value = ""
                Exit Sub
             Else
                MsgBox "PHA SN not exist in a database"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Other loop"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

IMPORTANT NOTICE:

I found the main issue. I made wrong if condition, it should be:
If Single_PHA <> "" Then previously I have got: If Single_PHA = True Then, and there the results is a value not the boolean type.

Everything works. Thank everyone very much for help.

Topic is ready to be closed.

PS: thank you Tom for suggestion and tip with debugger: )

Comment: Please provide a complete [mre] as is required. You can simply add a breakpoint by clicking in the gutter beside the line where you want to stop execution. Then, move mouse over variables to see their values, or add your variables to the "Watches" window.